# Mercurial: How do I revert a subrepo file?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I have a mercurial repo with a sub-repo (in this case, bootstrap).

I modified the file, then modified it back manually, but hg still thinks it's modified and won't let me commit my other changes (I don't want to commit anything to the sup-repo).

```
dl@Debian6:~/company/company-production$ hg status -S
M company/cms/static/less/index.less ## I want this file
M company/cms/static/vendor/bootstrap/less/carousel.less ## I DONT want this file
M company/templates/v2/homepage/carousel.html  ## I want this file
```

Above you can see the status thinks it's modified. But below when I run a diff carousel.less doesn't come up. Which is wierd to me.

```
dl@Debian6:~/company/company-production$ hg diff -S --stat
company/cms/static/less/index.less          |  13 +++++++++++--
company/templates/v2/homepage/carousel.html |  10 ++++------
2 files changed, 15 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

So I try to revert the suprepo file. But it doesn't let me.

```
dl@Debian6:~/company/company-production$ hg revert company/cms/static/vendor/bootstrap/less/carousel.less
company/cms/static/vendor/bootstrap/less/carousel.less: no such file in rev 57e22a1738af
```

**How do I revert the subrepo file: carousel.less, so I can commit my changes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the `bootstrap` directory so you are **in** the subrepo, then run:

```
hg revert less/carousel.less
```

(it *is* odd that `hg diff -S --stat` doesn't show the change, though.)

Comment: Fantastic. That worked. Though stupid me realised when I cd'd into it that bootstrap is a GIT repository NOT a HG repository. which is probably why my revert wasn't working. So I cd'd in, then used git checkout -- <file> and all was good :)